# Graphing Quadric Surfaces in PSTricks

Tags: xetex, pstricks, graphs, pst-solides3d, pst-3dplot

I am trying to make graphs of quadric surfaces that follow the illustrations in *Thomas' Calculus* book. One such illustration is the **ellipsoid** as shown below:
[image]

My work so far is as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[width=8.29in, height=11.64in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in, top=0.5in, bottom=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{pstricks, pstricks-add, pst-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\psset{unit=1}
\begin{pspicture*}(-5,-5)(5,6.5)
\pstThreeDCoor[linecolor=black,linewidth=1pt,IIIDxTicksPlane=xz, IIIDyTicksPlane=yz,spotX=180,xMin=-4,xMax=5,yMin=-2.25,yMax=4,zMin=-5,zMax=5,nameX=$x$, nameY=$y$, nameZ=$z$, labels=none] 


\parametricplotThreeD[xPlotpoints=200, linecolor=blue, linewidth=1pt, plotstyle=curve, algebraic](0,TwoPi){1*cos(t) | 2*sin(t) | 0}   % trace on xy-  plane

\parametricplotThreeD[xPlotpoints=200, linecolor=red, linewidth=1pt, plotstyle=curve, algebraic](0,TwoPi){1*cos(t) | 0 | 3*sin(t)}   % trace on xz-plane 


\parametricplotThreeD[xPlotpoints=200, linecolor=red, linewidth=1pt, plotstyle=curve, algebraic](0,TwoPi){0 | 2*cos(t) | 3*sin(t)} % trace on the yz-plane 



\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

The code above produces the following:

[image]

I do not know how to do the actual ellipsoid (i.e., the one in blue) as shown in the illustration above. I use **PSTricks** as some of my other work are also coded in PSTricks. Is there a way for me to mimic or copy the illustration above using PSTricks?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You might like to start here:  https://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=Examples/Gallery3D/Gallery3D  and then come back here when you have a specific question.   As it stands your question is not really in the sweet spot for this site.

Comment: @Thruston I have edited my post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a starter for `pst-solides3d` which makes more sense here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d,pst-plot}
\definecolor{coquille}{rgb}{0.984 0.95 0.718}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,4)
\psset{viewpoint=20 20 5, Decran=40,lightsrc=viewpoint,action=draw*}
\psSolid[object=ellipsoid,a=2,b=2,c=4,
  ngrid=54 24,base=0 360 -90 90,fillcolor=coquille,linewidth=0.01,
  intersectiontype =0,
  intersectionplan={[0 0 1 -1] [0 0 1 1] [2 0 1 1]},
  intersectionlinewidth=2 2 2,
  intersectioncolor=(blue) (red) (green)]
\axesIIID(2,2,4)(4,4,5)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But you need the latest version of the package, which is here or tomorrow on your system with an update from CTAN:
[https://hvoss.org/~voss/pst-solides3d.zip](https://hvoss.org/%7Evoss/pst-solides3d.zip)

Running `lulalatex` is slower than `xelatex`. There are heavy calculations for the 3d object.

The same with draw option `draw` and vertical line:

```
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,4)
\psset{viewpoint=20 20 5, Decran=40,lightsrc=viewpoint,action=draw}
\psSolid[object=ellipsoid,a=2,b=2,c=4,opacity=0.5,
  ngrid=54 24,base=0 360 -90 90,fillcolor=coquille,linewidth=0.001,
  linecolor=black!15,
  intersectiontype =0,
  intersectionplan={[0 0 1 -1] [0 0 1 1] [-1 2 0 0]},
  intersectionlinewidth=2 2 2,
  intersectioncolor=(blue) (red) (green)]
\axesIIID(2,2,4)(4,4,5)
\end{pspicture}
```

[image]

Comment: I get a message which says `The solid ellipsoid is not defined, the solid by default is drawn. \axesIIID`

Comment: And the link you posted above the `pst-solides3d` package is broken.

Comment: Ah, had the wrong filename. Now it works ... However, you should get it with the update of TeXLive/MiKTeX from today.